# Image gallery/slider, only showing one thumbnail but when click show a gallery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, wordpress

So like the title says. I want too have three "thumbnails" or pictures, then when you click eighter of them a slideshow of a gallery pops up (different gallerys for each thumbnail/picture). Can anyone recommend a good plugin for this? javascript/jquery/wordpress
Very good if it is responsive/fluid and works in most phones
Thank you!

Comment: google lightbox and you 'll get one

Comment: bipen: hmm looks like i have to show all pics that should be included in the gallery?
@PeteUh yes ofc i have. tried the most common gallery-plugins

Comment: fancybox http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GalleryView](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview)

[Prettyphoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)

[AD Gallery](http://coffeescripter.com/2009/07/ad-gallery-a-jquery-gallery-plugin/)

[FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

[Full Screen Gallery](http://devkick.com/blog/full-screen-image-gallery-using-jquery-and-flickr/)

[Slider Viewer Pro](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/svwt/index.html)

[Image Rotator with Description](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/create-an-image-rotator/)

[Pikachoose](http://pikachoose.com/)

[Galleria](http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/demo_01.htm#img/grass-blades.jpg)

[Apple Like gallery](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/)

[Banner Rotators with lots of function](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-banner-rotator-content-slider-carousel/full_screen_preview/1534434)

[A responsive multitouch slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/zuper-responsive-multitouch-slider/full_screen_preview/2028436)

and last from my side

[Nivoslider](http://nivozoom.dev7studios.com/)